# CSS gradient and background tile together does not cover full height of the page

Tags: wordpress, css

I can't for the life of me get this to work. My gradient and tile go together to the bottom of the page but when I scroll further they don't continue. I searched for the issue on here but couldn't find a solution and I'm not the best coder so.

The site can be seen here access code: 000 http://richlandgaming.qsandbox.com/

Thank you in advance!

```
body {
min-height: 100%;
color: #ffffff;
background: #242424;
background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/bg-tile.png"); /* fallback */
background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/bg-tile.png"), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#242424), to(#000000)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/bg-tile.png"), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #242424, #000000); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/bg-tile.png"),    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #242424, #000000); /* FF3.6+ */
background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/bg-tile.png"),     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #242424, #000000); /* IE10 */
background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/bg-tile.png"),      -o-linear-gradient(top, #242424, #000000); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/bg-tile.png"),         linear-gradient(top, #242424, #000000); /* W3C */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `html` element has a fixed height set to `100%` - removing that should fix your problem.

It's defined in your `style.css` at line `121`.

Comment: I cant edit the style.css cause I'm using wordpress I can only overwright it in the Appearance/Theme Options/CSS Styles by writing something than !important. What could I write which would overpower the fixed height?

Comment: html {height: auto !important;}

Comment: Thanks hugo, I updated the code with that however now its having some strange results when scale the browser window horizontally and vertically. The website link is above. Can you take a look?